# ViewPager not setting listview listeners when first created

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a viewpager swipeview (with 3 tabs) and a listview in each tab. However, I want the amount of tabs to be flexible which is why I do not want a listview for each tab. This means I'm using the same listview for each tab.

My problem is that I want users to be able to drag and drop items in the listview. This all works fine if I swipe back and forth to update the fragment but it doesn't the first time my fragment is created. Why? And how can I fix this?

Thanks!

In activity OnCreate:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager() );

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
ViewPager mViewPager = ( ViewPager ) findViewById( R.id.container );
mViewPager.setAdapter( mSectionsPagerAdapter );

TabLayout tabLayout = ( TabLayout ) findViewById( R.id.tabs );
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager( mViewPager );
```

Here is my fragment code:

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
        {

            /**
             * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
             * fragment.
             */
            private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            private DropListener mDropListener =
                    new DropListener()
                    {
                        public void onDrop (
                                int from,
                                int to
                                           )
                        {
                            listViewAdapter.onDrop(
                                    from,
                                    to
                                                  );
                            listView.invalidateViews();
                        }
                    };

            private RemoveListener mRemoveListener =
                    new RemoveListener()
                    {
                        public void onRemove ( int which )
                        {
                            listViewAdapter.onRemove( which );
                            listView.invalidateViews();
                        }
                    };

            private DragListener mDragListener =
                    new DragListener()
                    {

                        int backgroundColor = 0xe0333333;
                        int defaultBackgroundColor;

                        public void onDrag (
                                int x,
                                int y,
                                ListView listView
                                           )
                        {
                        }

                        public void onStartDrag ( View itemView )
                        {
                            itemView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                            defaultBackgroundColor = itemView.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
                            itemView.setBackgroundColor( backgroundColor );
itemView.findViewById( R.id.image_view_list_view );
                        }

                        public void onStopDrag ( View itemView )
                        {
                            itemView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                            itemView.setBackgroundColor( defaultBackgroundColor );
itemView.findViewById( R.id.image_view_list_view );
                        }

                    };

            public PlaceholderFragment ()
            {
            }

            /**
             * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
             * number.
             */
            public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance ( int sectionNumber )
            {
                PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                Bundle              args     = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(
                        ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
                        sectionNumber
                           );
                fragment.setArguments( args );
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView (
                    LayoutInflater inflater,
                    ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState
                                     )
            {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_temp_new_form,
                        container,
                        false
                                                );

                textViewValues = new ArrayList<>();
                checkBoxValues = new ArrayList<>();

                switch ( getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) )
                {
                    case 1:
                        textViewValues.add( "Android List View from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "Adapter implementation from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "Simple List View In Android from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "checkboxes" );

                        checkBoxValues.add( "first from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        textViewValues.add( "Android List View from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "Adapter implementation from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "Simple List View In Android from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "null" );
                        textViewValues.add( "test" );
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        textViewValues.add( "Android List View from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "Adapter implementation from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        textViewValues.add( "Simple List View In Android from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                listView = ( ListView ) rootView.findViewById( R.id.listView3 );
                listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(
                        getContext(),
                        textViewValues,
                        checkBoxValues
                );
                listView.setAdapter( listViewAdapter );
                ( ( DragNDropListView ) listView ).setDropListener( mDropListener );
                ( ( DragNDropListView ) listView ).setRemoveListener( mRemoveListener );
                ( ( DragNDropListView ) listView ).setDragListener( mDragListener );
                return rootView;
            }
        }
```

SectionsPagerAdapter:

```
/**
  * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
  * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
  */
        public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        {
            public SectionsPagerAdapter ( FragmentManager fm )
            {
                super( fm );
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem ( int position )
            {
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class above).
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance( position + 1 );
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount ()
            {
                // Show x total pages.
                return 3;
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle ( int position )
            {
            switch ( position )
            {
                case 0:
                    return "SCOUT 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SCOUT 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SCOUT 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```